# pub get failed. exit code 65. flutter

Tags: flutter-dependencies

Everything is ok. every package is working. but the shimmer package not working.
[this is my implementation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBEKb.png)

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies: 
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shimmer:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

---

error:

```
[shimmer] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in shimmer...                         
Error on line 26, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.

   ╷


26 │   shimmer:
   │   ^^^^^^^

   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
exit code 65
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the **project name** and **package name** are the same. It will throw an error.

So, make sure the **project name** and **package nam**e must be **unique**.

For example, You created a project, you gave it the name **provider**. and you also added a package which is the **provider**. So, they will conflict with each other.

Comment: I already fixed it. The same wrong I did which is what you said.